# A few tags to burninate

Tags: discusión, etiquetas

We haven't decided what to do with all our tags, but a few we seem to know we don't want.

I encourage anyone with the ability to edit any questions with the following tags to remove these tags.  And while you're at it, edit anything else in the question that can be improved!

- [phrase](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phrase) - This is a meta tag, and should be removed, and possibly replaced with other useful tags.
- [expression](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/expression) - This seems to be a mixture of *phrase*, *idiom* (now *modismos*), and possibly other uses.  Lets change all of these as well.
- [connotations](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/connotations) - Some of these may be better as *selección-de-palabras* or *word-usage*.

As these tags are cleaned up, they can be removed from this list, and other tags may be added here, as we determine they should be removed.

Comment: It's a big jump from "Some of these may be better as *selección-de-palabras* or *word-usage*" to "DO NOT USE -- This tag should be avoided."  Can you explain how you got from A to B?  See related meta post: https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3200/9385